# TypeError (Jest Test) why would this test fail? Error says function is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

> TypeError: (0 , _validators.validateEmail)(...).toBe is not a function

Is the error

**Here is my test**

```
// Utils
import { validateEmail, validatePassord } from './validators';

describe('validating email addresses', () => {
  it('should return true with a valid email', () => {
    expect(validateEmail('test@email.com').toBe(true));
  });

  it('should return false with an invalid email', () => {
    expect(validateEmail('badEmail').toBe(false));
  });
});
```

**The utility it's testing**

```
export const validateEmail = email => /@google.com\s*$/.test(email);

export const validatePassord = (password) => {
  const hasSpecial = /[!]+/.test(password);
  const hasAlpha = /[a-zA-Z]+/.test(password);
  const hasUppercase = /(?=.*[A-Z])+/.test(password);
  const hasNumber = /[0-9]+/.test(password);
  const hasMinChars = password.length >= 8;

  return hasSpecial && hasAlpha && hasUppercase && hasNumber && hasMinChars;
};
```

They are in the same directory. Error output:

[image]

Comment: Maybe your paren is in the wrong place, have you tried `expect(validateEmail('badEmail')).toBe(false);`?

Comment: That was it, @Kulix do you want to post the answer?

Comment: It's posted... glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving your parens around to something like...

`expect(validateEmail('test@email.com')).toBe(true);`

or something like this for the second test

`expect(validateEmail('badEmail')).toBe(false);`